# Solve this recurrence: F(n)=2∗F(n−1)∗2n+1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I was asked to solve this recurrence:

$F(n) = 2 * F(n - 1) +  2^{n+1}$ ; with $F(0) = 0$

I should solve this recurrence with two appraoches: with the characteristic function and with cascading. I know how both techniquese work, but I could not really solve the equation.

Firstly, with the characteristic function:

I ended up with

$F(n) - 2 * F(n - 1) =  2^{n+1}$ (which would mean $(x - 2) * (x - 2) = 0$)

Since there should be a number $ x^n * n^0$ on the right side and not $ x^{n+1} * n^0$, I do not know how to continue (of course, I know that $ 2^{n+1} = 2 *  2^n$). If I calcuate the root with $2^{n+1}$ or $4^{(n+1)/2}$, I get a wrong closed formular for the recurrence. Could you please tell me how to get something of the form $x^n * n^0$ on the right side of the equation?

Secondly, with cascading:

I ended up with something like $ F(n) = ((((2 * 0 + 2^1) * 2 + 2^2) * 2 + 2^3) * ... ) * 2 + 2^{n+1} $

But how do I conclude a concrete formula (if my approach is correct)?!

I would be really happy if someone could help me.

All the best!

Comment: for $n \geq 1$, $F(n)=2^{2n}$

Comment: $F(0) = 0;
F(1) = 2 * 0 + 2^2 = 4;
F(2) = 2 * 4 + 8 = 16;
F(3) = 2 * 16 + 16 = 48;$

But $2^6 = 64$ and not 48?!

Comment: AFAIK $4=2^{2*1}$

Comment: Sorry, my bad $F(n) = n2^{n+1}$

Comment: But how did you come up with that closed formular?

Answer (score 1):

I conjecture that $F(n)=n\cdot 2^{n+1}$ we get that
$$n\cdot 2^{n+1}=(n-1)\cdot2^{n+1}+2^{n+1}=n2^{n+1}$$
I got this by computing $F(1)=4$ and $F(2)=16$ and $F(3)=48$ the $48$ was really helpful since it's $3\cdot 16$ and we are computing $F(3)$ to confirm my guess I also computed up to $5$ and we get $F(5)=5\cdot 64$.